# jql to find the projects based on additional assignee in jira

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I'm trying to find out how I can create a filter to only show me the projects where I am assigned as additional assignee to an issue.

to explain; Currently my board consists of multiple projects with their versions and epics. For the epics, I can click on a version (of a project) to filter out the ones applicable to the version. However, I also do not want to see the projects where I am not in the "additional assignee" field.

My current filter simply picks all projects and checks this field for my name, but the downside is that the list of projects & versions is still shown (even though I have nothing to do with the project).

How can I create a filter that somehow filters out the correct projects?

Comment: What is the actual JQL?

Comment: JQL = Jira Query Language

Answer (score 0):

This **sample** shows the issues, where the *user* has been assigned, but is not the reporter.

JQL: `assignee = <user-id> AND reporter != <user-id>`

**Remarks**

- Replace the field *reporter* with the *additional assignee* one.
- When looking for the *additional assignee* field, start typing in the JQL box, it will come with suggestions, for fields.
- Update the `<user-id>`